# Ascii character codes in Excel and VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a textbox on a userform where users can input text. Sometimes users paste text into the textbox. Sometimes "weird" characters are pasted. I run some VBA-code to check if ASCII codes of all the characters are allowed according to a custom list.

Unfortunately some of the "weird" characters have the same ASCII codes as a "normal" character, even though the two characters is obviously different.

Here's how the two characters look in the userform textbox:

[image: 1]

The first character is a normal hyphen, the other one I don't know what is.

When I in VBA extract the ASCII codes for both characters it's 45 for both (45 is a hyphen). I use the VBA function `Asc`.

When I extract the ASCII codes in Excel, it gives me 45 for the first character and 63 for the other (63 is a question mark). I use the Excel function `CODE`:

[image: 2]

As you can see the characters look the same in appearance in Excel but have different ASCII codes.

I would like to know what I can do in VBA to distinguish between the characters.

Comment: Both VBA and Excel cells store strings in Unicode. Applying `Asc` or the sort to them makes little sense as soon as you step out of the first 128 values of the ASCII table (which you do). Use `AscW`. `CODE` gives you the question mark because it converts the character into ASCII, which cannot be done because it has no mapping there, and in the case of a mapping failure a `?` is used as a replacement.

Comment: GSerg's comment seems to cover it. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Maybe someone can help you with a work-around? To see if you have a real hyphen, can you do a comparison between a known hyphen and the weird character in VBA? Something like `If rng.Value = "-" Then`  or maybe `If rng.Value = Chr(45) Then`  where `rng.Value` contains the "weird" character? Then you would know if it is a real hyphen or not and you could handle is appropriately.

Comment: As @GSerg points out `Asc` isn't even for ASCII and your characters are not ASCII. Programmatically, all characters use the UTF-16 encoding of the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. That's why VB4 and VBA introduced the `AscW` and `ChrW` functions.

Comment: Gserg answered the question. How can I mark his answer as the final answer?